# Angular 5 - Receive POST requests

Tags: html, angular

**Scenario:** My angular page should be receiving a `POST` request with JSON data from SpringBoot API.

**Consider this as a work example:** When client clicks on login on an angular webpage, the login info would be sent through JSON to SpringBoot where it will validate the user,if it returns true, the same JSON would then be forwarded back to webpage as `POST`, where it will be captured and then worked on(displayed for example).

Now, as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309514/angular-5-post-requests-for-my-page), it is said that POST requests cannot be received on Angular but need Express for the same. Is it true? or is there any other way to receive `POST` requests from API using Angular? I'm googling on this from many days and haven't found anything relevant that confirms this and needed a closure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular is a library for providing a user interface in a browser (which is a type of HTTP **client**).

To listen for an HTTP request you need an HTTP server (such as Apache HTTPD, Lighttpd, NGINX, something built with Node.js+Express, etc, etc, etc).

> is there any other way to receive POST requests from API using Angular?

No

---

> should be receiving a POST request with JSON data from SpringBoot API.

Spring is a Java framework for running a webservice.

Typically it **receives** HTTP requests and makes HTTP responses.

While you could make HTTP requests from it (i.e. when a client makes an HTTP request to a Spring API, the Spring API then makes an HTTP request to another web service and uses the data in the response to construct its own response to the original request)…

… it sounds like you have the wrong end of the stick and really need to make an HTTP POST request **from** Angular **to** Spring and then read the HTTP **response** in Angular.

i.e. [Ajax](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6).

Comment: Yea, Ideally, `make an HTTP POST request from Angular to Spring and then read the HTTP response in Angular`  thing is done but also needed to think other way round. Thank you so much for the clarification! :)

Comment: Hi Sanket, how you read the POST data in Angular Component, Would you please elaborate on this. I want to do the same in one scenario

Comment: @Rohit subscribe to the response of the `POST`