# Angular - how to receive data from other page using post

Tags: angular, redirect, post

I have two applications, different domains. When the user enters one application and clicks a button, I want to open the other application sending one param.
This other application is **Angular** and I'm trying to receive this param through Post.
I saw this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50446204/angular-5-receive-post-requests) from two years ago saying I would need an API for example.
Is there a new way to receive this param in **Angular** nowadays?

This is the code from the first application:

```
post(obj, url) {
    const mapForm = document.createElement('form');
    mapForm.target = '_blank';
    mapForm.method = 'POST';
    mapForm.action = url;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(param => {
        const mapInput = document.createElement('input');
        mapInput.type = 'hidden';
        mapInput.id = param;
        mapInput.name = param;
        mapInput.setAttribute('value', obj[param]);
        mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
    mapForm.submit();
}
```

How can I receive this param on the **Angular** side?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you can communicate two front-end applications through a POST. If you send it through a GET it would be achievable. Just send the parameters in the url and then you can get the data through the route.

Comment: @ViníciusMussato, yeah I know I can make it work through query string, but I would go for it only when I'm out of options you know?

Comment: @ViníciusMussato What I could do though, is to create a hash on the first application, send it to an API with the param and store it on the DB. Then open Angular sending the hash through query string, and the Angular could get the para from the API and DB sending the hash...

Comment: That might work but it is just way too complicated. You dont need the hash at all. If you´re gonna use an API just use it the normal way.

Comment: @ViníciusMussato yeah... I'm overcomplicating things. But I still would like to know what other options I have.